# Array having issues in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is what I am trying to do,

```
// declare an array with 16 items, each with intial value = 0
var countMe = [
    ["00", 0],
    ["01", 0],
    ["02", 0],
    ["03", 0],
    ["10", 0],
    ["11", 0],
    ["12", 0],
    ["13", 0],
    ["20", 0],
    ["21", 0],
    ["22", 0],
    ["23", 0],
    ["30", 0],
    ["31", 0],
    ["32", 0],
    ["33", 0]
];

// calculate number of items for each array item by adding +1 to its previous value
$.each(dataFruits, function (index, item) {
    if (item.weight > -1 && item.quantity > -1) {
        countMe["" + item.weight + item.quantity, 1][1] = countMe["" + item.weight + item.quantity, 1][1] + 1;
    }
});

// go through array and call method for each array item whose value is more then zero
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (countMe["" + i + j, 1][1] > 0) {
            CreateText(countMe["" + i + j, 1][1], "black", 33, countMe["" + i + j, 0][0]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Issues**

1. I am not able to get value of array
2. I am able to update its value

It doesn't throw any errors, just doesn't give me any value.

Comment: what is this `"" + item.weight + item.quantity, 1` comma syntax ?

Comment: @argentum47 if I don't put "" then it will take weight and item quantity as number, so for 0 and 0 it will give me "0" when i expect "00"

Comment: i think you have wrong idea about array here, array elements are accessed by numbers , 0 1 ...2 i.e. the index of elements inside array. Try printing out the countMe after dataFruits loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are supposed to use a normal JavaScript object (key-value pairs) for this case.

```
// Create a JavaScript object
var countMe = {};

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j += 1) {
        // Create new keys and initialize them with 0.
        countMe["" + i + j] = 0;
    }
}

console.log(countMe);
```

would be

```
{ '10': 0,
  '11': 0,
  '12': 0,
  '13': 0,
  '20': 0,
  '21': 0,
  '22': 0,
  '23': 0,
  '30': 0,
  '31': 0,
  '32': 0,
  '33': 0,
  '00': 0,
  '01': 0,
  '02': 0,
  '03': 0 }
```

thus we created a JavaScript object and then you can count like this

```
$.each(dataFruits, function (index, item) {
    if (item.weight > -1 && item.quantity > -1) {
        countMe["" + item.weight + item.quantity]++;
    }
});
```

here, `countMe["" + item.weight + item.quantity]++` will increment the number corresponding to `"" + item.weight + item.quantity`. For example, if the `weight` is `1` and `quantity` is `2` then the value becomes `countMe["12"]` and the value against it will be incremented.

Now that you counted the values, you can call the function, like this

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i += 1) {
    for (var j = 0; j < 4; j += 1) {
        if (countMe["" + i + j] > 0) {
            CreateText(countMe["" + i + j], "black", 33, "" + i + j);
        }
    }
}
```

**Actual Problem**

When you do

```
countMe["" + item.weight + item.quantity, 1]
```

the indexing part

```
"" + item.weight + item.quantity, 1
```

will always be evaluated to be `1`, because the comma operator gives the last element in it as the result of the expression. You can confirm that like this

```
console.log((1, 2, 3, 4));
// 4
```

or

```
var a = (1, 2, 3, 4);
console.log(a);
// 4
```

So, you are always accessing `["01", 0]` as that is the element at index `1` and then you are always incrementing only that value.

Answer (score 0):

I think the array should either contain all strings or all integers.

```
var arr = [01, 0];
```

Or

```
var arr = ["01", "0"]
```

You should prefer first method for easy calculations..